# mongoDB design - to embed or not to embed

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a mongoDB database with 3 collections:

- widgets
- thingomajiggers
- locations

The way the application is going to be used that I will always force the user to specify a location first.  and then from there, they can drill down into the type object they are looking to read / create / update - namely either a widget or a thingomajigger.

So in this case, would it be better to have a separate location collection and refer to this collection from the documents in widgets and thingomajiggers, or should I embed location information right inside my widget / thingomajigger documents?

Currently my prototype is small so I can't imagine me really noticing performance differences.  But eventually I will have hundreds of thousands of widgets and other object types.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found my answer from the mongoDB manual:

In general, use embedded data models when:

- you have “contains” relationships between entities. See Model One-to-One Relationships with Embedded Documents.
- you have one-to-many relationships between entities. In these relationships the “many” or child documents always appear with or are viewed in the context of the “one” or parent documents. See Model One-to-Many Relationships with Embedded Documents.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/

The later scenario would apply to me.